# Scala factory pattern and concurency

Tags: scala, design-patterns, akka, factory-pattern

Hoping for some help with understanding scala further.

I often see this being presented as a factory pattern:

```
trait Animal 
private class Dog extends Animal 
private class Cat extends Animal

object Animal {   
    def apply(kind: String) = kind match {
       case "dog" => new Dog()
       case "cat" => new Cat()   
    } 
}   
Animal("dog")
```

I am wondering what this means as far as concurency, given the use of an object. Is using a factory pattern such as this "good enough" when servicing many clients? Could the factory be a pool of actors being accessed round-robin? Is there a better futures-based approach? I would like to avoid factory patterns becoming bottlenecks in designs where there is a lot of short-lived Animal instances being created.

Or am I just misguided worrying about the factory being a bottleneck?

Comment: That is a lot of questions, and a bit of a leap from the example given above.  Could you narrow it a little?   Concurrency is all about contention against the mutation of shared state, there is no mutation in the example above so in this case one is fine.  But one could not generalize that to all uses of the builder pattern.  If you are worried about the JVM contention of allocating objects, then please clarify and we can talk about that.

Comment: I think you worry too much. This is simple object creation.

Comment: You don't have any mutable state, so no need to worry at all

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Your `apply` method can be called in parallel by as many thread as you want. It's not sharing any mutable state.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I guess I didn't quite understand the concept well. My thoughts were that since an "object" is a singleton, I would have to contend with "locking" inside the apply method. But as it was pointed out, there is no state in this example. The comments do help clarify, thanks all.